# How to Mock non-existent file import in nodejs Lambda

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, proxyquire, mock-fs

I am facing issue in testing where My logger is in lambda layer thus non-existing for nodeJs import in lambda.js during mocha-chai testing. I tried mock-fs but getting errors **Can not find module /opt/logger.js** or maybe I am trying wrong way and not sure if it is useful in this way. Please check below code for reference. Any help or suggestion is most welcome.

lambda.js -

```
const logger = require('/opt/logger.js') // coming from lambda_layer.js
```

lambda.test.js -

```
mock({
    "/opt/logger.js": console.log('hello')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to accomplish this with mockery. Thanks for allowing me to put this here for everyone. Will update this with better code soon.

```
mockery.registerMock({'/test/': { destroyAllHumans: actionStub })
mockery.enabled();
```

Comment: How to do that using Jest framework?